# Put six quick-toggles in Note 3 menu

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3. The 'slide down menu' [1] can be configured with 'quick-toggles' [1] at the top. A maximum of **five** 'quick-toggles' can be displayed at any one time, with the remainder of configured 'quick-toggles' available by sliding the 'quick-toggles' control to the left.

My particular use case is that I do need to **see at a glance *six*** 'quick-toggles'. Scrolling to see the sixth is a hindrance to my particular use case. First-world problem, I know! **How can I configure or hack the 'slide down menu' to show *six* thinner 'quick-toggles' on the display at once?**

[1] *This is my first Android device. Please correct my terminology so that I might be able to Google these questions myself next time!*

Answer (score -3):

Use Wanam Xposed or Wanam Kit. It's an Xposed Framework module that will allow you to change everything about the toggles